# How to include formatted text in XPath?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am working on a project for my IT job that requires me to write a scraper using Scrapy/XPath to get a fairly simple set of data from a fairly simple HTML page. I've gotten everything to work the way I want it to, with the exception of some italic text (the website being scraped is for a language education program and there are many instances of italics in this specific text field) not showing up.

Below is the code I have used successfully before the italics issue came up:

```
rawTitles = []
for sel in response.xpath('//h2[@class="video"]'):
    rawTitle = sel.xpath('text()').extract()
    rawTitles.append(rawTitle[0])
print rawTitles
```

I get the following return for "print rawTitles":

```
[u'\n', u'\nVariations in Making ', u'\nMaking ', u'\nCommon Rice and Meat Dishes', u'\nRumens and ']
```

What I want is something like this:

```
[u'\n<i>Mjadra</i>', u'\nVariations in Making <i>Mansaf</i>', u'\nMaking <i>Maqloobeh</i>', u'\nCommon Rice and Meat Dishes', u'\nRumens and <i>Mahashi</i>']
```

If the literal HTML tags cannot be included in the output, I would at least like the plaintext to be included. Blank spaces where words should be just doesn't seem like the best I can do.

Does anyone know what I might want to try? Let me know if I didn't supply enough information. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is an example of a table entry from which I need to extract info:

```
<td width="25%" valign="top" align="center">
<h2 class="video"><img src="content/pl_makingfood_mjadrah.jpg"     alt="Thumbnail image from video" width="160" height="120" /><br /><br />
<i>Mjadra</i></h2>      <p class="video">Video <br />

<a href="content/pl_makingfood_mjadrah.rm" class="main">real</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="content/pl_makingfood_mjadrah.mp4" class="main" target="_blank">mp4</a><br /><br />

Palestinian Arabic &amp; English <br />
<a href="content/pl_makingfood_mjadrah.doc" target="_blank" class="main">  doc </a>&nbsp; &nbsp; 
<a href="content/pl_makingfood_mjadrah.pdf" target="_blank" class="main">  pdf </a></p>
</td>
```

Comment: Can you provide sample input HTML?

Comment: I've just added some; let me know again if it's not much help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at different extraction patterns in scrapy shell, building a selector from your sample HTML:

```
>>> import scrapy
>>> t = '''<td width="25%" valign="top" align="center">
... <h2 class="video"><img src="content/pl_makingfood_mjadrah.jpg"     alt="Thumbnail image from video" width="160" height="120" /><br /><br />
... <i>Mjadra</i></h2>      <p class="video">Video <br />
... 
... <a href="content/pl_makingfood_mjadrah.rm" class="main">real</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
... <a href="content/pl_makingfood_mjadrah.mp4" class="main" target="_blank">mp4</a><br /><br />
... 
... Palestinian Arabic &amp; English <br />
... <a href="content/pl_makingfood_mjadrah.doc" target="_blank" class="main">  doc </a>&nbsp; &nbsp; 
... <a href="content/pl_makingfood_mjadrah.pdf" target="_blank" class="main">  pdf </a></p>
... </td>'''
>>> selector = scrapy.Selector(text=t, type="html")
```

First, let's loop on `<h2 class="video">` elements (using CSS selectors), and extract a string representation of each heading inside the loop:

```
>>> for h2 in selector.css('h2.video'):
...     print(h2.xpath('string()').extract())
... 
['\nMjadra']
```

We loose the `<i>` information.

Let's try getting only text nodes (with `text()` node test):

```
>>> for h2 in selector.css('h2.video'):
...     print(h2.xpath('text()').extract())
... 
['\n']
```

Even worse than before, we are not getting text node inside `<i>` elements. (Indeed, `text()` selects only direct children text nodes, not children of children)

Let's try with `.//`, a.k.a `./descendant-or-self::node()/` shortcut:

```
>>> for h2 in selector.css('h2.video'):
...     print(h2.xpath('.//text()').extract())
... 
['\n', 'Mjadra']
```

Not much better than using XPath's`string()`.

Now, let's use `node()` node test, capturing elements and text nodes:

```
>>> for h2 in selector.css('h2.video'):
...     print(h2.xpath('node()').extract())
... 
['<img src="content/pl_makingfood_mjadrah.jpg" alt="Thumbnail image from video" width="160" height="120">', '<br>', '<br>', '\n', '<i>Mjadra</i>']
```

That's better but we have these `<img>` tags that you may not want. So let's pick only text nodes and `<i>`s:

```
>>> for h2 in selector.css('h2.video'):
...     print(h2.xpath('./node()[self::text() or self::i]').extract())
... 
['\n', '<i>Mjadra</i>']
>>>
```

You may want to get a single string out of each heading. So using Python's `join()` is an option:

```
>>> for h2 in selector.css('h2.video'):
...     print( "".join(h2.xpath('./node()[self::text() or self::i]').extract()) )
... 

<i>Mjadra</i>
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

With `text()` called on an element you *only get the top-level text nodes* while you want to go down to every child element as well, use `.//text()`:

```
rawTitles = response.xpath('//h2[@class="video"]//text()').extract()
```

You can then join the items of a `rawTitles` list with `str.join()`, but i would recommend looking into [Item Loaders](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) and input and output processors - there is `Join()` processor that would be suitable in this case.

Or, to follow Paul's advice in comments, use [`string()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/string) XPath function:

```
rawTitles = response.xpath('string(//h2[@class="video"])').extract_first()
```

Comment: I would recommend using XPath's `string()` functions `rawTitles = response.xpath('string(//h2[@class="video"])').extract_first()`

Comment: I will try these solutions in a few minutes--I had already tried replacing "text()" with ".//text()" and got the exact same result, but it sounds like it's more complicated than that anyway. Thank you both, and I'll report back with results.

Comment: Now that I re-read the question, I believe `text()` or `string(...)` would miss the "keep italic information" (`<i>Mjadra</i>`) request.

Comment: Something like `rawTitle = "".join(sel.xpath('child::node()').extract())` should work